# using the loop to reach out to pictureBoxes

Tags: c#

I have pictureBox1, pictureBox2, picturebox3, .... in C# ,is there a way I can change the 1st picturebox background color with a loop,and wait, and then change the background of pictureBox2?

would be something like this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
        {
            pb.BackColor = Color.Red;
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
    }
```

but I get this error

> Error 1   Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls'
>   cannot be used like a
>   method.   C:\Users\test\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 22  37  WindowsFormsApplication1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the threadpool (as some have noted, this may cause threading exceptions, though it didn't for my test or for you... will depend where you call this code from I believe):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        pb.BackColor = Color.Red;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
     }
 });
```

In repsonse to Jeff Bridgman:

I was also surprised he didn't get an exception, but I tested it out and it is working fine. Just for completeness though (it may cause exceptions depending on where this code is called from), here is a safe version:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{
    foreach (var pb in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        var pb1 = pb;
        pb1.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
            {
                pb1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }));
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
});
```

Just a note about why I used `var pb1 = pb;` inside the loop (I've had this question from a co-worker). [Here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Access+to+modified+closure) is a good explanation from the ReSharper wiki.

Comment: You don't get cross-thread exceptions from this? You don't need to get back on the UI thread?

Comment: @JeffBridgman: See update (I was also suprised that it wasn't causing an exception).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds you need something like;

```
foreach(var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    pb.BackColor = Color.Red;
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: That's because `Controls` is not a method, it is a property. Just omit the (): `var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()`

Comment: @Lasooch Ups! My mistake. Updated.

Comment: Now It freezes the whole application and then turns the pictureboxes into red at once.

Comment: Maybe try adding an Invalidate() call? I'm not sure and can't test right now.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the `Controls` collection is not a method, but a property of the form, and the error says exactly that, th cannot be used like a method.

In short, change this line:

```
foreach (var pb in this.Controls().OfType<PictureBox>())
```

To this:

```
foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
```

Note the missing parenthesis after `Controls`